# Shortest distance between a circular arc and a line segment

Tags: geometry, line

I need to find the shortest distance between a 2d circular arc and a finite non-zero length line segment. Would be great to also know the two points, one on the arc and the other on the line segment the make up for the shortest distance. the language doesn't really matter, even pseudo code would be highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Find the closest point on the circle to the line. (That's an easy formula to look up.) If that point is within the arc, you have your answer. If it is on a part of the circle not included in the arc, select the closest point that is within the arc.

Comment: But then i still would need a solution to find the shortest distance between an arc and a line?

Comment: You said "circular arc." So, it's part of a circle. The distance from the circle to the line is the distance from the circle's center to the line, minus the radius. If that point is not within the arc, then the closest end point of the arc would be your answer.